# How to handle a share intent(sending an image) in the expo app?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

Is there any way to handle sharing files to expo app? According to the [documentation of app.json](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/) it's possible to provide `intentFilters`, but I can't find anything regarding handling them afterwards.

Ejecting is not an option.

Comment: Have you looked at Linking? [Handling links into your app](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/#handling-links-into-your-app). A bit further down it also contains a section about handling data passed to the app.

Comment: Yes, I did, but it only gives a url looking like `exp://exp.host/@community/native-component-list`, but no image info

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to do it?

Comment: Hey @RobinBobin, sadly not, but I don't work with expo these days.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation says

> To add or edit intent filters in an ExpoKit project, edit AndroidManifest.xml directly.

You can see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) how to add an intent filter in the manifest, that define the activity (in the example `ShareActivity`) that will handle receiving text (you can remove this part) or images

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <!-- This activity handles "SEND" actions with text data -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- This activity also handles "SEND" and "SEND_MULTIPLE" with media data -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google.panorama360+jpg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then, in your activity in expo.io, you need to get the extra from the `Intent` and you will have the info of the attached image

Comment: He's not using Expokit but a managed expo app(And ejecting isn't an option). So this, unfortunately, won't be possible.

Comment: I'm not using expokit and I know how to add intent filters(I have a link to docs in a question). What I don't know is how to handle the image from the app.

Comment: For example to handle notifications it's possible to add `Notifications.addListener(listener)` and handle notifications in `listener` callback. I was hoping something similar exists for share intents